# ls in a directory for a list of files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ls

I have a C codebase, all resides in the same directory.
I want to find all the header files that have a code file with the same name.

Right now, I have the following command:

```
ls *.h | sed s/.h/.c/
```

This returns a 'list' of filenames that I want to search for. How can I pass this list to another command so that I can see which header files have code files sharing the same name?

Comment: Wow, thank you everybody. I'm going to take the easiest answer, but I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without any external command:

```
$ for i in *.h
> do
>   [ -f  ${i/.h/.c} ] && echo $i
> done
```

The first line loops through every file.

The third line is a test construct. The `-f` flag to `test` (aka `man [`) checks to see if the file exists. If it does, it returns `0` (which is considered true in shell). The `&&` only operates if the following command if the previous line returned successfully.

${i/.h/.c} is an in-place in-shell regex substitution so that the file tested is the corresponding .c to the .h.

Comment: Ah, that moment of providing not what was asked for, but what was needed!

Comment: @JeffFerland : Why did you put the $? Its not giving correct result with $.

Comment: I put the `$` to anchor it to the end of the line. While in practice that nobody will have a .h.h file, it was good form. Of course, since it broke for you then there's something shell-dependent about that. I'll pull it back out, though it did work for me.

Comment: @JeffFerland : Thank Jeff . I understood why you put it. But, when I tried it in my bash(3.2), it was not working fine. Thanks for reverting  and for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

you could use xargs which transforms its input:

```
a
b
c
```

to an argument list:

```
a b c
```

So this should print "a b c":

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc" | xargs echo
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ls `ls *.h|sed s/.h/.c/` 2>/dev/null
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
ls *.h | sed s/.h/.c/ | xargs ls 2>/dev/null
```

The remainder of the command runs `ls` again with the new *.c filenames. `ls` will complain about every file that doesn't exist, so we redirect stderr to nowhere.

Example without `2>/dev/null`:

```
$ ls
a.c a.h b.c c.c d.h
$ ls *.h | sed s/.h/.c/ | xargs ls
ls: d.c: No such file or directory
a.c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -1 *.c* *.h*|awk -F. '{a[$1]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i]==2)print i".hh"} }'
```